# Custom capability for a single user

Tags: users, capabilities

I have this complex scenario:

1) I'll have multiple admin users.

2) Only one admin can 'see_encrypted_pass'

Now, I want to assign custom 'see_encrypted_pass' capability to only one admin (say, John). I have a restricted page containing encrypted password. I want to use this on that page-

```
if(current_user_can('see_encrypted_pass')){
    //show encrypted password
}
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself :)
I just added custom capability to the user-

```
$user = new WP_User(1); //1 is the admin ID
$user->add_cap( 'see_encrypted_pass' );
```

Then checked-

```
if(current_user_can('see_encrypted_pass')){
    //encrypted password
}
```

It works!!

Comment: Remember to come back and accept your own answer after the restriction is lifted :-)